# bound value in conditional binding must be of optional type

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

in line **if let ip = indexPath?**, I am getting the following error: *bound value in conditional binding must be of optional type*

What do I do to **indexPath** to fix this issue?

<>

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellId:String = "Cell"
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellId) as UITableViewCell

    if let ip = indexPath? {
        cell.textLabel?.text = myData[ip.row] as String
    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: This is strange: `indexPath` is not optional, yet you get this error instead of "operand of postfix '?' should have optional type"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexPath` in not an optional type (i.e `NSIndexPath?`) so there is no need to unwrap it with `if let ip = indexPath?` (hence the error message)

You can use it as is :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellId:String = "Cell"
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellId) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = myData[indexPath.row] as String

    return cell
}
```

Comment: no just do not use the if statement, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The indexPath is not an optional value. So it's value will not be `nil` in any condition.

So you can't write like (can't unwrap non-optional value):

```
if let ip = indexPath?
```

So change the code like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let CellId:String = "Cell"
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellId) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = myData[indexPath.row] as String
    return cell
}
```